# No module named sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have tried using sudo easy_install sqlalchemy, pip install sqlalchemy and pip install flask-sqlalchemy. I have also tried installing and uninstalling sqlalchemy and flask. I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 267, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/j/Downloads/ng-website-master/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/hupper/worker.py", line 264, in worker_main
    func(*spec_args, **spec_kwargs)
  File "/home/j/Downloads/ng-website-master/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid/scripts/pserve.py", line 40, in main
    return command.run()
  File "/home/j/Downloads/ng-website-master/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid/scripts/pserve.py", line 222, in run
    app_spec, name=app_name, relative_to=base, global_conf=vars)
  File "/home/j/Downloads/ng-website-master/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 247, in loadapp
    return loadobj(APP, uri, name=name, **kw)
  File "/home/j/Downloads/ng-website-master/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 272, in loadobj
    return context.create()
  File "/home/j/Downloads/ng-website-master/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 710, in create
    return self.object_type.invoke(self)
  File "/home/j/Downloads/ng-website-master/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 146, in invoke
    return fix_call(context.object, context.global_conf, **context.local_conf)
  File "/home/j/Downloads/ng-website-master/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/util.py", line 55, in fix_call
    val = callable(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/j/Downloads/ng-website-master/ngse/__init__.py", line 15, in main
    config.include('.models')
  File "/home/j/Downloads/ng-website-master/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid/config/__init__.py", line 776, in include
    c = self.maybe_dotted(callable)
  File "/home/j/Downloads/ng-website-master/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid/config/__init__.py", line 876, in maybe_dotted
    return self.name_resolver.maybe_resolve(dotted)
  File "/home/j/Downloads/ng-website-master/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid/path.py", line 320, in maybe_resolve
    return self._resolve(dotted, package)
  File "/home/j/Downloads/ng-website-master/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid/path.py", line 327, in _resolve
    return self._zope_dottedname_style(dotted, package)
  File "/home/j/Downloads/ng-website-master/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid/path.py", line 382, in _zope_dottedname_style
    __import__(used)
  File "/home/j/Downloads/ng-website-master/ngse/models/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    import zope.sqlalchemy
ImportError: No module named sqlalchemy
```

Even after trying to upgrade sqlalchemy, I get the above error have.

```
Requirement already up-to-date: sqlalchemy in ./venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

Tried upgrading flask-sqlalchemy,still get the same error

```
Requirement already up-to-date: flask-sqlalchemy in ./venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already up-to-date: SQLAlchemy>=0.8.0 in ./venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from flask-sqlalchemy)
Requirement already up-to-date: Flask>=0.10 in ./venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from flask-sqlalchemy)
Requirement already up-to-date: itsdangerous>=0.21 in ./venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from Flask>=0.10->flask-sqlalchemy)
Requirement already up-to-date: Jinja2>=2.4 in ./venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from Flask>=0.10->flask-sqlalchemy)
Requirement already up-to-date: Werkzeug>=0.7 in ./venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from Flask>=0.10->flask-sqlalchemy)
Requirement already up-to-date: click>=2.0 in ./venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from Flask>=0.10->flask-sqlalchemy)
Requirement already up-to-date: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in ./venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from Jinja2>=2.4->Flask>=0.10->flask-sqlalchemy)
```

I am trying to install use sqlalchemy inside a virtualenv. I also have python=2.7.14, pip=9.0.1, setuptools=38.2.5 and **the supposed installed sqlalchemy=1.2.0**. I used supposed because when I try upgrading and checking the version of sqlalchemy and flask-sqlalchemy, my computer shows that it's installed but I can't use it.

Here's what I get when I print out sys.path

```
['', '/usr/lib/python2.7', 
'/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', 
'/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', 
'/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', 
'/home/j/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', 
'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.5-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg', 
'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/SQLAlchemy-1.2.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg', 
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']
```

Please help me. I don't know what else to do

Comment: by any chance do you have multiple versions of python ?

Comment: I tried checking and only saw python 3.6.3 and python 2.7.14

Comment: this seems issue to me, may be when you're running python then python3 gets invoked but all the packages are installed for python2.7, can you open cmd and go to `c:\Python27\` and type `python.exe` and check which version of python is picked up on the first line

Comment: I'm using Lubuntu and can't run python.exe. Using python --version and readlink -f $(which python) | xargs -I % sh -c 'echo -n "%: "; % -V' I get 2.7.14

Comment: if it is Lubuntu then just type `python` on terminal and check first line on console

Comment: Typing python prints out Python 2.7.14 (default, Sep 23 2017, 22:06:14)

Comment: You're missing the [`zope.sqlalchemy`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/zope.sqlalchemy) package for some reason, not SQLAlchemy. The way Python 2 displays the exception is misleading, compared to Python 3, which would show `No module named 'zope.sqlalchemy'` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You're pip install is wrong.

Change sqalchemy to sqlalchemy so it is:

```
pip install sqlalchemy
```

And make sure to do so within the activated virtualenv.

Comment: Sorry, missed that while typing. I'll edit it now. I did use pip install sqlalcemy inside an activated virtualenv. Still get the same error

Answer (score 1):

I get the same error as you.
I solved it with:

1. I remove my virtrualenv, and create a new one
2. run `pip3 install -r requirment.text`  install of `sudo pip3 install -r requirment.text` (if above command get permission denied error, you should run `sudo chown -R user /usr/local/lib/python3.6/`)